# Выборка поля из одной таблицы и COUNT() из другой

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

Доброе время суток. Назрел вопрос, и хочется решить его более элегантно.

Имеется 2 таблицы (`a` и `b`):

```
 a.id | a.name         b.id | b.aid | b.use
------+--------       ------+-------+-------
   1  | Petya            1  |   1   |   0
   2  | Vanya            2  |   2   |   1
                         3  |   1   |   0
                         4  |   1   |   1
                         5  |   2   |   0
                         6  |   1   |   1
                         7  |   1   |   0
```

На выходе нужно получить:

```
 a.id | a.name | count_total | count_busy
------+--------+-------------+------------
   1  | Petya  |      5      |     2  
   2  | Vanya  |      2      |     1
```

где:

- `count_total` - количество элементов c `a.id = b.aid`.
- `count_busy` - количество элементов c `a.id = b.aid и b.use = 1`

Возможно ли данную задачу осуществить одним запросом? Как это лучше сделать?

- Для [@Yaant](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/32625/yaant): исправил опечатку: `3` на `2`.
- Для [@Yura Ivanov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6117/yura-ivanov): на практике еще не пробовал, но первое, что приходит на ум — вложенные запросы.

Comment: Какие варианты пробовали вы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
      a.id
    , a.name
    , count(*) as count_total
    , sum(case when b.use > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as count_busy
FROM a inner join b on a.id = b.aid
GROUP BY a.id, a.name;
```

Вроде так

Answer (score 3):

```
Select
  a.id,
  a.name,
  count(*) as count_total,
  sum(b.use) as count_busy
from
  a,b
where
  a.id = b.aid
group by
  a.id, a.name;
```

Подходит?

Comment: Моя вина, что не указал сразу, но use не является булевым. use может принимать значение 0-999

Comment: @pavel Используйте ANSI join, см. описание метки [sql]

Comment: @YuraIvanov а чем `join` лучше чем условие в `where`?

Comment: Мой комментарий не ради дискуссии, а просьба придерживаться единообразия в ответах по sql, о чем, как я уже сказал, написано в описании метки. Если вас интересует "лучше" или не "лучше", задайте отдельный вопрос или поищите информацию сами, например см. здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax