# Запрос к двум таблицам MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть две таблиц.

В одной рубрике объявлений: `board_cats` со структурой: `|cat_id|cat_title|...|`

В другой сами объявления:  `board_items` со структурой `|item_id|item_title|...|item_cat_id|`

выбираю список рубрик по алфавиту

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM board_cats ORDER BY cat_title ASC";
    $result = $inDB->query($sql) ;
    if ($inDB->num_rows($result)){
        while($item = $inDB->fetch_assoc($result)){
           $massiv[] = $item;
        }
    }
```

всё работает, это просто.

Теперь надо к каждой выведенной рубрике добавить счётчик, сколько там объявлений. А вот тут уже я так понимаю нужны JOIN-ы, в которых я пока ни бум-бум, хотя пытался разобраться на примерах.

То есть, логика такая - в board_items ищем объявления, у которых `item_cat_id = cat_id`, считаем их, и сумму пишем в массив. А вот как это сделать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Уже обсуждалось в [этом вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539493/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B8-count-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, всё верно, для этого вам нужно соединение таблиц. Так как не у всех категорий могут быть объявления, рекомендую использовать `left join` вместо обычного `join` (почитать про типы соединений [можете тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) и [ещё тут](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html)):

```
select bc.cat_title,
       count(bi.item_id)
from board_cats bc left join board_items bi
     on bc.cat_id = bi.item_cat_id
group by bc.cat_title
```

Здесь дополнительно идёт группировка по полю `bc.cat_title`, чтобы можно было использовать агрегатную функцию [`count`](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_getting_summarizing_values.html).

Пример на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfbe50/1/0).

Comment: Огромное спасибо, после _count(bi.item_id)_ добавил _as items_count_, и вышло то, что мне надо!

Comment: @АлександрВладимирович всегда пожалуйста.

Comment: доброй ночи. У меня немного усложнилась задача по этому вопросу, и я снова за помощью к вам)) попробую объяснить сейчас.

Comment: В общем, count(bi.item_id) сейчас считает количество записей в каждой отдельной рубрике. Как оказалось, у меня будут ещё и вложенные рубрики, и сейчас нужно сделать так, чтобы count у родительской рубрики считал общее количество записей и в ней, и во всех вложенных рубриках. В таблице board_cats появился дополнительный столбец parent_id, обозначающий id родительской рубрики.